# what is the best way to extract from a line in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

what is the best way to extract from a line (for ex the line is :  `-user <username> -id <userid> -sub <subname>`) in a file. But the length line may vary with extra attributes like -user,-id,-sub .

The output should be :-

```
{
"user" : username
"id" : userid
"sub" : subname
}
```

Comment: Best way for what? You could do this with some string splitting

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes I could do it via string split . And the attributes may vary in a line . Do you think string split is faster than regex?

Comment: I have no idea, it needs to be measured. Also, maintainability of the code matters more than raw performance in most cases. Non-trivial regexes are harder to grasp than string splits.

Comment: @RiyazuddinM check my answer. does it solve your problem?

Comment: @rock321987 I am able to ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using `JSON` for this. I have hardcoded quotes and colon

```
import re
arr = re.findall("-(.*?)<(.*?)>", "-user <username> -id <userid> -sub <subname>")

for x in arr:
   print "\"" + x[0].strip() + "\" : ", x[1].strip()
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/4CRD5j)**

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>import re
>>> print("{\n"+re.sub(r'-(\w+)\s*([^-]+)\s*', r'"\1": "\2",\n', "-user <username> -id <userid> -sub <subname>").strip('[\n,]')+"\n}")
{
"user": "<username> ",
"id": "<userid> ",
"sub": "<subname>"
}
>>>
```